# Commit size much higher than the Working Set

Tags: sql-server, memory, windows-server-2012

In one of our Windows servers hosting SQL Server database instances, I could see a drastic difference in the commit size and working set for one `SQLServer.exe` process (from Resource Monitor)

- Commit(KB): 162 186 000
- Working Set (KB): 1 296 800

I understand that commit size includes RAM used + Virtual Memory. I checked the size of `pagefile.sys` in the server and found it to be only 8GB large. So where is the rest of the virtual memory accommodated? On the RAM itself?

Kindly clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a complex topic, and if you want really detailed answers you can read a lot of deep and informative articles about how the OS handles "memory", like [this old one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/markrussinovich/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-virtual-memory).

But if you want an executive summary: The "commit charge" may not have been allocated in RAM or on disk at all! It represents a commit of "virtual address space", which is a kind of "map".

When a process "adds" to its commit charge, here's what's really happening: It says to the OS "hello I want to use X amount of memory please", and the OS says "OK, I guarantee you access to X amount of memory". It does this by "allocating" address space in the virtual address space "map". But *that's just a map*. It doesn't mean any memory has *actually* been allocated yet - either from RAM, or from disk!

By way of analogy, imagine you are booking a hotel room. You call the hotel and say "Hello, I would like a room this Saturday and Sunday please". The receptionist looks at the booking calendar and sees that room 28 is free. They tell you "OK, I have you booked in for this Saturday and Sunday". Here, the receptionist's calendar is the "map" of "virtual room space". The receptionist has guaranteed you this room by updating the map. But you're not *actually* using the room yet. You're not in it, none of your bags or clothes are in it. You've just made the booking.

The commit charge includes all of the "bookings" your application has made, and the operating system is the receptionist. Your application may not be using the booked space yet, but the operating system has guaranteed that you can use that space if you want to.

Comment: Thank you allmhuran for your summary.. It did share some insight into how the OS deals with virtual address space. But in my case, it seems most of that Virtual address space was reserved in the RAM and that reserved space was actually being counted as utilized memory. Earlier the SQL Server instance was set to have a Max server memory of ~160GB and we later brought it down to 80GB and along with it the total server memory utilization dropped from 93% to 74%.

Comment: @aok Yeah, committed memory *can* be guaranteed by ram, or by disk, and once guaranteed it can be used by the process. There are also certain kinds of memory allocations that show up in different ways. These allocations may not show up in the "working set", despite being part of the commit charge *and* in RAM. Most of the ram being used by a SQL Server will be the buffer pool. If a Sql server starts paging, it's probably a Sql server that's going to die, so it wants "real RAM".

Comment: I think that the size is the size of the allocation in the VAD and commit is possibly the amount of page table entries there are that aren't null (which includes valid (hardware) PTEs, page file PTEs, transition PTEs) and might also include VAD PTEs and PTEs pointing to prototype PTEs